# Looping Java Audio

Tags: java, javax.sound.sampled

I've got my `Clip` loaded.

I can start the `Clip` using the method `clip.start()`.

However, once the song ends, the clip stops playing (duh).

How do I make it loop continously until I call `clip.stop()`?

```
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
URL url = this.getDeclaringClass().getResource("file.wav");
AudioInputStream s = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
clip.open(s);
```

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using?

Comment: @gariepy, sure, I don't see why not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should probably use `clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);` rather than `clip.start()`